# Differentiate between zoom in and out in scalegesturedetector android

Tags: android, pinchzoom

Cant differentiate if user is zooming in or out using scaleGestureDetector

```
mZoomGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getActivity(), new OnScaleGestureListener()
        {

            int intFactor=0;
            boolean firstVisited = false;

            private float mScaleFactor2;
            private float currectScale= -100;
            private float startScale;
            private float endScale;

            @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
            {
                endScale = detector.getScaleFactor();

//this condition does not pass. not > or < succeeds
                if (startScale > endScale) {
                    Log.i("onScaleEnd", "Pinch Dection");
                } else if (startScale < endScale) {
                    Log.i("onScaleEnd", "Zoom Dection");
                } 
                setFontSize(intFactor);

            }


            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
            {

                startScale = detector.getScaleFactor();

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
            {
                //Log.i("ScaleFactor", "Scale Factor original " + detector.getScaleFactor());

                mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor() * 100;



                Log.i("ScaleFactor", "Scale Factor : On  " + mScaleFactor);

                intFactor = (int) mScaleFactor;


                return true;
            }
        });
        ;
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it as follow :

```
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
            {

                double scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                if (1.0f > scaleFactor) {
                    mode = 0;//Log.i("ScaleFactor", "Pinch Dection");
                } else  {
                    mode = 1;//Log.i("onScaleEnd", "Zoom Dection");
                } 

}
```

Comment: it is too sensitvie, how you can reduce the sensitivity?